# Compare two columns and enter a number in a third

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with 3 columns. I need to compare two columns and if they match I need to put the number in the third column in a fourth column.

I have attached two examples below. I need to compare names and put the attendance % in in the last column.

Example 1:

[image: Example]

Example 2:

[image: Example 2]

Comment: here is an example

Comment: This is a fairly complicated task. To a human, Abbot, Rollin should be the same as Abbot, Rollin James. In excel, they are different.  Finding a match for Addie without anything else is hard. There are methods to get around, but it is more than a answer typically can cover,  What have you tried so far?  Do you have any control on the source side. Can you bring in additional fields such as student number?  Matching numbers is a whole lot easier than matching names with different name formats

Comment: I have now got the columns of names to match.

Comment: See example 2.  I need to compare B and F and if they match I need to put the %that is in E in column I

Answer (score 0):

Put that statement in first cell, where you want to input comparation results:

=IF(A1=B1,”Match”,”Didn't match”).

I assume you compare A column with B column.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compare B and F, and put E in I if it's true, then in I2 (or wherever the top one starts) put:

```
=IF(B2=F2,E2,"")
```

Then drag it down to automatically complete it.
If the result in I2 is 0.98 rather than 98%, you can use this function instead.

```
=IF(B2=F2;E2*100&"%";"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the names are not in the same order will need to do a Vlookup with an iferror.

1. Set the input range
   Can not see the row numbers, will assume a 100 entries going from B2 to E102 which results in $b$2:$E:$102
2. Set the VLookup
   =+VLOOKUP(F2,$B$2:$E$102,4,FALSE)
   This uses the value in f2 to find a match in the input range and then returns the value from the E column. The false means it must match exactly for this to work.
3. Add the iferror
   if there is no match from the vlookup, then a error is returned. The iferror converts the error message into "Did not match" or someother message of your choice. My normal would be "" which leaves the cell blank.

Everything combined is

- iferror(VLOOKUP(F2,$B$2:$E$102,4,FALSE),"Did not Match")